# Using keyboard actions to open files outside of Python

Tags: python, excel

Brand new to programming....

I am trying to set up a program that can be controlled using keyboard shortcuts. I want the keyboard shortcuts to be linked to specific excel files. I have figured out how to open the excel files by themselves but now I want to attach the shortcuts to them. This is all I have:

```
import os
os.system('start C:\mold\MoldFlowMaster_exce.xlsx')
```

Comment: There's no built-in way to register globally accessible keyboard shortcuts. You have to interface with the OS' API (say, with pywin32) and watch for keyboard state changes manually (say, by calling [`GetKeyboardState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) every tenth of a second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes a Tkinter window which you can type in to. If the 'shortcut' (in this code, 'a') is pressed, you can cause something to happen such as opening your Excel file.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

def onKeyPress(event):
    if event.char == 'a':
        os.system('start C:\mold\MoldFlowMaster_exce.xlsx')

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
text = tk.Text(root, background='black', foreground='white', font=('Comic Sans MS', 12))
text.pack()
root.bind('<KeyPress>', onKeyPress)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a good approach as long as OP doesn't mind that the shortcut only works when his program's window has focus. It's unsuitable as a general purpose [boss key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boss_key), but fine for some kind of workflow-managing application.